# Autommaper error in second project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, automapper

i have problem with my project WebApi, by using AutoMapper.

In my solution i use AutoMapper v4.1.1, solution old and have a lot of code inside.

Where is 4 projects

- Core - service and extention
- DataLayer - DataLayer and repository
- MVC - standart web form project
- WebApi - new project with Api functionality

in this solution i use:

1. Entity FrameWork 6.1.1
2. AutoMapper 4.1.1

connection strings in WebConfig to local DB base on SqlServer.

i have two models, **User** - its DataBaseEntity, and **UserModel** - this is BussinesModel

My AutoMapper class in DataLayer looks so

```
namespace DataLayer
{
 internal static class Mapping
{
    static Mapping()
    {
        RegisterMappings();
    }

    public static TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source, TDestination destination)
    {
        return Mapper.Map(source, destination);
    }

    private static void RegisterMappings()
    {
        try
        {
            Mapper.AllowNullDestinationValues = true;
            //Mapping instruction for User
            Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserModel>().IgnoreAllPropertiesWithAnInaccessibleSetter().ReverseMap();

            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        }
     }
}
```

in CoreLayer i use this code

```
 public AuthenticationResult Login(string login, string password)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(login))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(login));

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(password));

        using (var db = new Context())
        {
            try
            {
                //Here my UserDbEntity model, and it already connected from Context
                var dbUser = db.Users.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(u => u.Login == login && u.IsActive && !u.IsDeleted);
                //mapping model
                var model = Mapping.Map(dbUser, new UserModel());

                //Some result logic here

                return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

all references to Projects inside WebApi and WebFroms Mvc project is same (references to DataLayer and CoreLayer)

and now the problem, than i call action

```
CoreLayer.Login(string login, string pass)
```

from my MVC project, he return me correctly data
and if i do so from Web Api project he show me error

```
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
        Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
        ==================================================================
        ServiceModel -&gt;Service (Source member list)
        Core.Models.ServiceModel -&gt; Data.DB.Service (Source member list)

        Unmapped properties:
        Specialization
        ServiceTechnic
        ServiceTools
        RefRescueWorkTypes
```

all this unmapped members is complex objects (model inside model), and have own rules to mapping. While i working in MVC project, they mappet correctly

P.S Sorry for my English, it`s not my native language

**UPD 1 for @Alexandru Marculescu**
example of unmmaped models,

*Source* 
PersonalInformation Entity

```
internal partial class PersonalInformation
{            
    public override System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    //link to related Address entity
    public Nullable<System.Guid> AddressId { get; set; }
    public string EMail { get; set; }
    // a lot of string properties here, nothing intresting    
    internal virtual Address Address { get; set; }      
}
```

Address entity

```
 internal partial class Address
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Address()
    {
       this.PersonalInformations = new HashSet<PersonalInformation>();
    }

    public override System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    //hardcoded Id inside code
    public System.Guid RegionId { get; set; }
    public System.Guid DistrictId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> LocalityId { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string House { get; set; }
    // a lot of string properties here, nothing intresting   

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    internal virtual ICollection<PersonalInformation> PersonalInformations { get; set; }
}
```

bussines model

```
 public class AddressModel
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public Guid RegionId { get; set; }       
    public Guid DistrictId { get; set; }
    public Guid? LocalityId { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string House { get; set; }
    //one-to-many
    public List<PersonalInformationModel> PersonalInformationModels {get;set;}
 }

 public class PersonalInformationModel
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string FullName{ get; set; }

    public Guid? AddressId { get; set; }

    public string EMail { get; set; }

    private AddressModel _address;
    public AddressModel Address
    {
        get
        {
            if (AddressId.HasValue && App.CreateCommonService().Addresses.Get(AddressId.Value).Value != null)
                return App.CreateCommonService().Addresses.Get(AddressId.Value).Value;

                return _address;
        }
        set { _address = value; }
    }
  }
```

and mapping instruction for this

```
 internal static class Mapping
{
    static Mapping()
    {
        RegisterMappings();
    }

    public static TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source, TDestination destination)
    {
        return Mapper.Map(source, destination);
    }

    private static void RegisterMappings()
    {
        try
        {
            Mapper.AllowNullDestinationValues = true;

            Mapper.CreateMap<Address, AddressModel>().ForMember(x=>x.PersonalInformationModels , o=> o.MapFrom(s=>s.PersonalInformations.ToList())).IgnoreAllPropertiesWithAnInaccessibleSetter().ReverseMap();

            Mapper.CreateMap<PersonalInformation, PersonalInformationModel>()
                .ForMember(x => x.Address, o => o.Ignore()).IgnoreAllPropertiesWithAnInaccessibleSetter().ReverseMap();

  Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) when (App.CreateLogService().WriteError(ex))
        {
            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

And this how i call mapping from my services

```
var item = new PersonalInformationModel();
//some input logic and *item* become full
var dbEntity = Mapping.Map(item, new PersonalInformation());

var item = new AddressModel();
//some input logic and *item* become full
var dbEntity = Mapping.Map(item, new Address());
```

And for this classes i get error look like this

```
 Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
        Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
        ==================================================================
        AddressModel -&gt;Service (Source member list)
        Core.Models.AddressModel -&gt; Data.DB.Address(Source member list)

        Unmapped properties:
        PersonalInformations
```

All references for Linq, Core, Entity frameworks same in both projects, .Net framework version 4.6, connection strings same in web.configs (in both projects) but MVC work good, an Api give me unmapped error.

Comment: Are the name and data types of the unmapped properties same in the source and destination?

Comment: could you please show us the source & destination models? @SillyJohn - if they would be, they'd get _auto_mapped;

Comment: @SillyJohn, nope, name and datatypes are diffreent, but they have `.ForMember()` rules inside, and mapped correctly then i use MVC project

Comment: @AlexandruMarculescu question updated